# Asynchronous Web Methods

Tags: c#, .net, asmx

I have a client/service.

The service has a method that takes a long time to do (it interacts with a database).

I'm call this method via a AJAX request from the page to the client, then to the service and back.

My service code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string LookupUPC(string sessionId, string upc) {
    string response = "";
    var client = new SmartShopService.SmartShopInterfaceClient();
    try {
        response = client.LookupUPC(sessionId, upc);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    finally {
        if (client.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Faulted)
            client.Abort();
        else
            client.Close();
    }
    return response;
}
```

It is called from the page by an AJAX request

```
for(var i = 0;i<10; i++){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SmartShopGUI.aspx/LookupUPC",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: DataCreator(allData),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        $(upcName).html(result.d);      
    },
    error: AjaxFailed
});
}
```

Now, this is done asynchronously on the page, but the client is sending the requests synchronously. I want to change it so that if it asks for 10 all at once, it'll send 10 different requests to the service.

http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cX1Qo8qV2

Here is a video that might help.

Comment: I don't think you've given us enough information... how is the client sending them synchronously?  Where is this `Loader` defined and where is it calling this Ajax load?

Comment: What do you mean by loader? I know the client is sending them synchronously, because I sent 10 AJAX requests to the WebMethod but through breakpoints I noticed that each request waits for a previous one to finish. The client is just an ASPX page.

Comment: @Overload119 I mean this line in the ajax call: `Loader.RequestsMade--;`..  Seems to me like there is something called Loader that is making these calls and counting down...

Comment: It's just an integer variable that I'm decrementing. I'll remove it, as it doesn't really pertain to the question.

Comment: @Overload119 What is confusing is... where are the 10 calls? how do 10 calls get triggered?  That does not appear to be shown here...

Comment: Assume a for loop around the ajax requests. Updated again.

Comment: Not an answer, just a hint: get rid of the `catch` block. All it does is confuse the stack trace by making it look like the exception came from inside the catch block.

Comment: @Overload119 So you're saying the ajax works fine, but the WebMethod is blocking?

Comment: Yes, the AJAX requests get through and don't hang the page (so they are being asynchronous in that sense) but the next AJAX request is pending until the first one is completed (meaning, WebMethod is blocking I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the reliance on Session in the webmethod, you'll probably find that session access is serial and that is what the block is.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

> Concurrent Requests and Session State
>
> Access to ASP.NET session state is
>   exclusive per session, which means
>   that if two different users make
>   concurrent requests, access to each
>   separate session is granted
>   concurrently. However, if two
>   concurrent requests are made for the
>   same session (by using the same
>   SessionID value), the first request
>   gets exclusive access to the session
>   information. The second request
>   executes only after the first request
>   is finished. (The second session can
>   also get access if the exclusive lock
>   on the information is freed because
>   the first request exceeds the lock
>   time-out.) If the EnableSessionState
>   value in the @ Page directive is set
>   to ReadOnly, a request for the
>   read-only session information does not
>   result in an exclusive lock on the
>   session data. However, read-only
>   requests for session data might still
>   have to wait for a lock set by a
>   read-write request for session data to
>   clear.

Comment: Can you go into more detail - mind you, the WebMethod code is within an ASPX page not an ASMX service. Would it still work?

Comment: Sorry posted the link before seeing your comment.  Try putting the attribute [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(false)] and making sure you aren't using session in the method.

Comment: You could try putting this ' If the EnableSessionState value in the @ Page directive is set to ReadOnly, a request for the read-only session information does not result in an exclusive lock on the session data. However, read-only requests for session data might still have to wait for a lock set by a read-write request for session data to clear.'

Comment: Okay, here is what I did from what I understand. EnableSessionState is not in the @Page directive at all, so I didn't touch it. I put WebMethod(false) but it didn't help.

Comment: Really you can't do this? <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" %>

Comment: You are very welcome.  Just as a side bar you'll notice the same behaviour through out the asp.net framework customer handlers, pages etc...

Answer (score 1):

You would do better to create a BatchLookup API that can handle a block of requests all in one go.  Any connection between a browser and a server will be limited as to how many simultaneous requests you can make and each round trip is a slow operation itself.

**I suspect that this isn't a server-side issue at all but the browser connection limitation that you are hitting.**  Even if you fix the server-side to handle two simultaneous requests the browser isn't going to fire off all 10 of them at once.  See for example this article on the topic: http://www.ajaxperformance.com/2006/12/18/circumventing-browser-connection-limits-for-fun-and-profit/

BTW, how can looking up a single UPC code in a database take so long?  Do you have it indexed properly?